# If there is no element $x \neq e$ in finite abelian group such that $x = x^{-1}$, then $a_1 a_2 \ldots a_n = e$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I am getting this problem from page 41 of Charles Pinter's A Book of Abstract Algebra. I really don't have any idea how to approach this problem.

Prove the following:

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group.

1. If there is no element $x \neq e$ in $G$ such that $x = x^{-1}$, then $a_1 a_2\ldots a_n=e$.
2. If there is exactly one element $x\neq$ e in G such that $x = x^{-1}$, then $a_1a_2 \ldots a_n=x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (1). Think that for every element $a \in G$, it's inverse is also in $G$. So once you take the product and use commutativity you can pair each element with its inverse and you get $e$.

For (2). Isolate that element which is its own inverse and pair the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Unique hint for both questions:

Observe that we can pair up **all elements but one** in $\;G\;$ as $\;(a_i,\,a_j)\;$ , with $\;a_ia_j=e\;$ . We're also given $\;i\neq j\;$ . Well, what then can you do with the product $\;a_1\cdot\ldots a_i\cdot\ldots a_j\cdot\ldots\cdot a_n\;$ ? What if there's only one element with $\;a_k^2=e\;$  ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Every element has its (unique) inverse in $G$, so due to commutativity (the group is abelian) $a_1a_2a_3\dots a_n$ can be rewritten in such an order that any element is next to its inverse.